# When can I use STL decomposition?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

Let us say I extract all tweets containing a certain hashtag (main subject of the tweet) and bin them by the hour i.e. count the number of tweets that occurred during a certain hour. I will then be obtaining a time series for this particular hashtag. I have recently come across the [STL decomposition](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs315/Papers/stl%20statistical%20model.pdf) which decomposes a given timeline into its seasonal, trend and error components and `R` provides a simple function `stl` to achieve this.

I am trying to understand if using this in my context (timeline of tweet counts) is appropriate. What I would like to examine is whether two given hashtags have a similar timeline and I was wondering what I can understand by using time series decomposition. Any suggestions?

Comment: In my opinion, it is appropriate, I assume that tweets timelines show a kind of seasonality, otherwise I wouldn't see the point of using a decomposition method.